# Вывод UNIX timestamp yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Пользуюсь виджетом \kartik\date\DatePicker;.
http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datepicker
 Запись даты в формате int. Как при обновлении отображать форматированную дату, а не int ?

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'date_of_birth')->widget(
                                DatePicker::className(), [
                                'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_INPUT,
                                'pluginOptions' => [
                                    'autoclose'=>true,
                                    'format' => 'yyyy-m-d',
                                ],
                                'options' => [
                                    'placeholder' => 'Дата рождения'
                                ],
                            ])->label(false);?>
```

В документации ответа не нашел, пробывал в атрибут 'value' подставить - все то же. Может кто-то решал уже данную звадачу ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переформатировать перед выводом?

```
$date = new DateTime($model->date_of_birth);
$date->setTimestamp($model->date_of_birth);
$model->date_of_birth = $date->formate('yyyy-m-d');
$form->field($model, 'date_of_birth')->widget( ...
```